# updating/editing a google with setValues without deleting my formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From my webapp in google apps script, I pass an object (=submitted user information) to by serverside code/function, which should update/edit the given information.
since I define the whole range of my row before, I am not able to "pass" certain cells with the setValues method to avoid "overwriting my formulas", which are in between the given range.
my code looks like this:

```
`    ws.getRange(rowNumber, 1,1,5).setValues([[
            userInfo.start,
            userInfo.finish,
            cell with FORMALA, if I put , , to omit that cells my formula gets deleted.
            userInfo.value1,
            userInfo.value2
     ]]);`
```

any advices how can I avoid deleting certain cells (without defining more "ranges" because above given code is shortend and much longer? (meaning: many more cells with formulas)

```
`const getformula = ws.getRange(row, 1, 1 , 15).getFormula()`
```

: only gives me the formulas.

```
`const displayValues  = ws.getRange(row, 1, 1, 15).getDisplayValues(); `
```

: gives me only the values

both trials don´t bring me closer.

Comment: Yeah that's unfortunate but that's what happens when you use formulas.  Its just another reason  I never use formulas.

Comment: @Cooper thank you for your response. looks like I have to adjust/restructure my sheet to make it easier for a web app. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Formulas are simply a string.  You can have both values and formulas in the same array and then using `.setValues()` placed into a spreadsheet.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Test");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let formulas = sheet.getDataRange().getFormulas();
    values.forEach( (row,i) => {
        row.forEach( (column,j) => {
            if( formulas[i][j] !== "" ) values[i][j] = formulas[i][j];
          }
        );
      }
    );
    console.log(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I - as newbie to apps script - get you right: There is no way in fetching the data first. I will try your suggest to find a way to adjust my array before doing my `.setValues()` approach.